# Testing Pinia changes in a Vue 3 Component Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, pinia, vitest, vue-testing-library

I have a component in my Vue 3 app which displays a checkbox.  The checkbox can be manually checked by the user but it can also be checked/unchecked as a result of a Pinia state change. I'm pretty new to Unit Testing but I would assume that a good unit test for this component would include checking whether or not the checkbox reacts to the Pinia state correctly.  However, in my Unit Test, when I change the Pinia state, the checkbox value does not change (the component itself works fine, it's only in the Unit Test that this does not work).  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

As well as calling the store action to update the state I have also tried store.$patch and that doesn't work either.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="field-checkbox">
    <Checkbox role="checkbox" :aria-label="displayName" @change="checkGroupMember()" v-model="checked" :binary="true" />
    <label>{{displayName}}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useContactBookStore } from "@/stores/contactBookStore";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
const store = useContactBookStore();
const props = defineProps({
  groupMember: { type:Object, required: true }
});
const checked = ref(false);
const { getCheckedGroupMembers } = storeToRefs(store)
const displayName = ref(props.groupMember.title + " " + props.groupMember.firstName + " " + props.groupMember.lastName);

// set the initial value of the checkbox
updateCheckBox();

// watch the value of getCheckedGroupMembers in the store and if it
// changes re-evaluate the value of the checkbox
watch(getCheckedGroupMembers , () => {
  updateCheckBox();
},{ deep: true })

// when the checkbox is checked/unchecked, run the checkUser method
// in the store
function checkGroupMember() {
  const groupMember = {
    id:props.groupMember.id,
    title:props.groupMember.title,
    firstName:props.groupMember.firstName,
    lastName:props.groupMember.lastName
  }
  store.checkGroupMember(groupMember,checked.value);
}

// the checkbox is checked if the user is among the checked users
// in the store
function updateCheckBox() {
  const groupMember = {
    id: props.groupMember.id,
    title: props.groupMember.title,
    firstName: props.groupMember.firstName,
    lastName: props.groupMember.lastName
  }
  const exists = getCheckedGroupMembers.value.find((member) => member.id === groupMember.id)
  checked.value = !!exists;
}

</script>
```

and this is my Unit Test:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/vue";
import GroupMember from "@/components/ContactBook/GroupMember.vue";
import { describe, it, vi, expect, beforeEach, afterEach } from "vitest";
import { createTestingPinia } from "@pinia/testing";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";

import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia";
import Checkbox from 'primevue/checkbox';
import { useContactBookStore } from "@/stores/contactBookStore";

describe("GroupMember", () => {

  const mockUser:GroupMember = {id:"TT001",title:"Mr",firstName:"Ted",lastName:"Tester"}

  let mockProps = {groupMember:mockUser};

  render(GroupMember, {
    props: mockProps,

    global: {
      components: {Checkbox},
      plugins: [PrimeVue,
        createTestingPinia({
          initialState: {contactBook:{checkedGroupMembers:[mockUser]}},
          stubActions: false,
          createSpy: vi.fn,
          fakeApp:true
        }),
      ],
    },
  });

  setActivePinia(createPinia());

  it("Displays the user name in the correct format", async() => {
    const displayName = mockProps.groupMember.title + " " + mockProps.groupMember.firstName + " " + mockProps.groupMember.lastName;
    screen.getByText(displayName)
  });

  it("Shows the checkbox initially checked", async() => {
    let checkbox:any;
    const displayName = mockProps.groupMember.title + " " + mockProps.groupMember.firstName + " " + mockProps.groupMember.lastName;
    checkbox = screen.getAllByRole("checkbox", { name: displayName })[1]
    expect(checkbox.checked).toBe(true)
  });

  it("Should display the checkbox as unchecked when the store is updated", async() => {
    let checkbox:any;
    const displayName = mockProps.groupMember.title + " " + mockProps.groupMember.firstName + " " + mockProps.groupMember.lastName;
    checkbox = screen.getAllByRole("checkbox", { name: displayName })[1]
    const store = useContactBookStore();
    await store.checkGroupMember(mockUser,false);
    //await store.$patch({checkedGroupMembers:[]})  // this didn't work either
    expect(checkbox.checked).toBe(false)
  });
});
```

this is the error I get when the test runs:

```
54|     expect(checkbox.checked).toBe(false)
       |                             ^
     55|   });
     56| });

  - Expected   "false"
  + Received   "true"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you render or mount a component in a unit test, there is no event loop running, so while you can change the state in the Pinia store, the component does not react to the alteration until "later": `import { flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils'; await flushPromises()`, `await component.vm.$nextTick` or `import { nextTick } from 'vue'; await nextTick()`.

See https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html where  it is described that you can `await` triggers like clicking on the checkbox, but if the change happens out of band, you don't necessarily have enough awaiting going on.

flushPromises is [documented here](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#flushpromises)

Comment: Thank you - that appears to have worked!